# Magento 2 - move city field

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

Do you know how I can move the "City" field before "Zip/Postal Code" in the Estimate Shipping and Tax part of the checkout cart?

[image]

Comment: It seems that you face a custom checkout. Search for checkout_cart_index.xml. You should find the fields there. Set your own order.

Comment: Can you please share your answer if you got this.